# How to ensure CoordinatorLayout children do not overlap

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-bottomappbar

I am using bottom app bar inside the coordinator layout. the rest of the content is coming from a fragment. the fragment content is being covered by the bottom app bar

Because I am using bottomAppBar it has to be inside a CoordintorLayout and all the children have to be inside of it as well. All layout above the BottomAppBar should fill the space reminding, but if I do so the views at the bottoms get covered. how do I ensure the view do not overlap with BottomAppBar

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".main.MainActivity">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_navHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:fabCradleMargin="4dp"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
    app:menu="@menu/main_navigation"/>
```

What I need is to ensure whatever content is replacing the fragment should not be covered by the bottom app bar and it should use all the white space not being used the bottom app bar. I another world the content should be above it while using rest the white space and still be inside the coordinator layout.

Comment: You're using `app:hideOnScroll="true"`, so it certainly seems like you are expecting the Fragment content to go under the `BottomAppBar`'s area.

Comment: Thank you @ianhanniballake for your comment. In some cases I do expect it to go under the bottomAppBar, in other cases not. So I guess I have to handle this from the activity not the layout. I will give it a try. Thanks again

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake I have done the change and removed the app:hideOnScroll="true" and it did work and I tried to set to false and still I have the same result. part of the view is still hidden behind the bar. any advice

Answer (score 2):

Just add `margin` to your fragment container :

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_navHost"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="{bottom_navigation_height}"
    android:layout_marginTop="{tool_bar_height}"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the help, but would you consider this a solution or a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CoordinatorLayout Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout), edges where a View in CoordinatorLayout expects to overlap with another View can be specified with `layout_dodgeInsetEdges=”bottom”`. So if your fragment is being overlapped by your BottomAppBar, you add this attribute to the fragment. You must also specify that you wish to dodge the BottomAppBar. This is done by adding `layout_insetEdge=”bottom”` to it.

To be more specific for your case, do the following:

Add `app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"` to the `<fragment>` like so:

```
<fragment
    app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom" <--- THIS
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_navHost"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

Add `app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"` to `BottomAppBar`. (Note that this step my be unnecessary if BottomAppBar applies this inset by default so try also without it):

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom" <---- THIS
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
    app:fabCradleMargin="4dp"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"/>
```

There's a [really good article](https://medium.com/@rusinikita/simple-view-dodging-with-coordinatorlayout-f13cc32e0de6) that shows examples with animated giffs that I highly recommend you to check out.

Comment: The link points to Constrain Layout Docs. Are you sure this the link you wanted to share,

Comment: Sorry, I must have gotten confused there. Will edit my answer for Coordinatorlayout instead of Constraint....

Comment: The problem with the solution it pushes the fragment to the top, which hides the tops views

Comment: @MustafaALMulla I had the same issue and after some digging I found out the solution. I updated the answer with detailed steps how to fix your issue. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the fragment.

Comment: I am not sure how this will help? could you please explain

Comment: I'm new to Coordinator layout. Adding this fixed my problem with my recycler view overlapping with appbar. But I'm not sure about the working.